# How to compress an array of dates to their months?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, momentjs, slice

I need to compress the array of dates to their months.

Using the slice method and the library moment.js, I want to compress the array to their months.

Here I get the last date of the month for the current date of the array.

```
const dateString = moment (lastIndexTemp, "DD.MM.YYYY")
        .endOf ("month")
        .format ("DD.MM.YYYY");
```

Given such an array with dates and data. I need to squeeze it to months.

```
const dates   = [
  { date: "26.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "27.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "28.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "29.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "30.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "01.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "02.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "03.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "04.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "05.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "06.07.2019",someData: "foo" },
   ... 
  { date: "08.08.2019",someData: "foo" }
];
```

Expected result:

```
const dates   = [
  { date: "26.06.2019 - 30.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "01.07.2019 - 31.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "01.08.2019 - 08.08.2019",someData: "foo" }
];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi, Please refer [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hello, thanks, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's cut up this task in to separate parts:

### Converting the date *strings* to momentjs objects

Since the strings in your input data represent dates, let's convert them before we do anything else. I define a helper function to construct new objects that parse the strings to moments:

```
const DateEntry = ({ date, someData }) => ({
  date: moment(date, "DD.MM.YYYY"),
  data: someData
});

const dateEntries = dates.map(DateEntry); // Now, we can use momentjs for our date logic
```

### Grouping date entries that belong together

Now that we have a list of dates, we can group them by month. I've implemented a quick `groupBy` helper which you can copy, or you can use one from libraries like underscore or ramda.

To group by month, we pass a function that returns a unique string per month:

```
const entriesByMonth = groupBy(
  ({ date }) => date.format("MM.YYYY"),
  entries
);
```

### Merging arrays of entries in to one item

Now we're stuck with groups of entries that are in the same date. You want to end up with a flat list of objects, and you want to grasp their range in the `date` label.

Again, we can define a helper function to convert these groups to objects that are easier to work with:

```
const EntryRange = ( dateEntries ) => {
  const dates = dateEntries.map(d => d.date);
  const data = dateEntries.map(d => d.data);

  const from = moment.min(dates);
  const to = moment.max(dates);

  return { dates, data, from, to };
};

const ranges = Object.values(entriesByMonth).map(EntryRange);
```

Now, we have a flat list of objects; one object per month of entries. The objects already know their start and end date!

### Converting back to your desired output

All there's left to do, is to write a function that converts the `EntryRange` object back to your desired format:

```
ranges.map(({ from, to, data }) => ({
  date: `${from.format("DD.MM.YYYY")} - ${to.format("DD.MM.YYYY")}`,
  data: data[0]
}))
```

Note that creating the string can utilize momentjs' format method!

### Putting it all together

Here's the code in a runnable snippet.

```js
// 1: Raw input data
const dates   = [
  { date: "26.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "27.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "28.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "29.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "30.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "01.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "02.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "03.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "04.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "05.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "06.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "08.08.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "01.01.2020", someData: "foo" },
];

// 2: Define models
const DateEntry = ({ date, someData }) => ({
  date: moment(date, "DD.MM.YYYY"),
  data: someData
});

const EntryRange = ( dateEntries ) => {
  const dates = dateEntries.map(d => d.date);
  const data = dateEntries.map(d => d.data);
  
  const from = moment.min(dates);
  const to = moment.max(dates);
  
  return {
    dates,
    data,
    from,
    to
  }
};

EntryRange.sorter = (r1, r2) => r1.from.isBefore(r2.from) ? -1 : 1;

// 3. Convert data to easy-to-work-with formats
const entries = dates.map(DateEntry);
const entriesByMonth = groupBy(
  ({ date }) => date.format("MM.YYYY"),
  entries
);
// Sorted list of EntryRanges
const entryGroups = Object
  .values(entriesByMonth)
  .map(EntryRange)
  .sort(EntryRange.sorter);


// 4. Convert back to desired output
console.log(
  entryGroups
    .map(({ from, to, data }) => ({
      date: `${from.format("DD.MM.YYYY")} - ${to.format("DD.MM.YYYY")}`,
      data: data[0]
    }))
)

// Utils
function groupBy(getKey, items) {
  return items.reduce(
    (groups, item) => {
      const k = getKey(item);
      if (!groups[k]) groups[k] = [ item ];
      else groups[k].push(item);
      return groups;
    }, {});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

### The benefits of splitting up these kinds of data transformations

Now that we've got a piece of code that cuts up every step, we can do a lot by writing small changes. I'm going to make two changes, just to show we can :)

1. Change the group logic to group by only year
2. Support joining different data entries by a `,`

Try it out yourself to see how you can get to different results!

```js
// 1: Raw input data
const dates   = [
  { date: "26.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "27.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "28.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "29.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "30.06.2019", someData: "bar" },
  { date: "01.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "02.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "03.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "04.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "05.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "06.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "08.08.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "01.01.2020", someData: "foo" },
];

// 2: Define models
const DateEntry = ({ date, someData }) => ({
  date: moment(date, "DD.MM.YYYY"),
  data: someData
});

const EntryRange = ( dateEntries ) => {
  const dates = dateEntries.map(d => d.date);
  const data = dateEntries.map(d => d.data);
  
  const from = moment.min(dates);
  const to = moment.max(dates);
  
  return {
    dates,
    data,
    from,
    to
  }
};

EntryRange.sorter = (r1, r2) => r1.from.isBefore(r2.from) ? -1 : 1;

// 3. Convert data to easy-to-work-with formats
const entries = dates.map(DateEntry);
const entriesByYear = groupBy(
  ({ date }) => date.format("YYYY"),
  entries
);
// Sorted list of EntryRanges
const entryGroups = Object
  .values(entriesByYear)
  .map(EntryRange)
  .sort(EntryRange.sorter);


// 4. Convert back to desired output
console.log(
  entryGroups
    .map(({ from, to, data }) => ({
      date: `${from.format("DD.MM.YYYY")} - ${to.format("DD.MM.YYYY")}`,
      data: [...new Set(data)].join(", ")
    }))
)

// Utils
function groupBy(getKey, items) {
  return items.reduce(
    (groups, item) => {
      const k = getKey(item);
      if (!groups[k]) groups[k] = [ item ];
      else groups[k].push(item);
      return groups;
    }, {});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new array of new objects by going over the current array and copying the first object to the array and updating the date property to the current range. Then for each subsequent object with a date that is the next day in the same month, just up date the date value of the last object in the result array.

Otherwise, add a new object to the array with an updated date value. This will create multiple ranges in the current month if there are breaks in the sequence of dates. It's not clear if that's what you want to do or not.

E.g. the following uses a couple of simple helpers to parse the string and add a day. You can replace those with library calls if you want.

It's not clear which "someData" you want to keep, the following keeps the first but you could easily keep the last instead.

```js
let dates   = [
  { date: "26.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "27.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "28.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "29.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "30.06.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "01.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "02.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "03.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "04.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "05.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "06.07.2019", someData: "foo" },
  { date: "08.08.2019", someData: "foo" }
];

// Parse DD.MM.YYYY to Date. Seperator can be
// any non–digit character
function parseDMY(s) {
  let b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[1]-1, b[0]);
}
// Return a new date that is the passed date + 1 day
function addDay(date) {
  let d = new Date(+date);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  return d;
}

let result = dates.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  // Copy the passed in object
  let temp = Object.assign({}, obj);
  // Get the last entry in accumulator, use a default object if first iteration
  let last = acc.length? acc[acc.length - 1] :  {date:' - '};
  // Get the current date as string
  let currentS = temp.date;
  // Get the current date as Date
  let currentD = parseDMY(currentS);
  // Get the previous end date as Date,
  let lastEndD = parseDMY(last.date.split(' ')[2]);
  // Get the next day as Date
  let lastEndNextD = addDay(lastEndD);

  // If current date is the day after last end date
  // and in the same month, update date range
  if (+currentD == +lastEndNextD &&
      currentD.getMonth() == lastEndD.getMonth()) {
    last.date = last.date.replace(/\S+$/, currentS)

  // Otherwise, start a new entry with an updated range
  } else {
    temp.date = temp.date + ' - ' + temp.date;
    acc.push(temp);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```